Update Ubuntu 22.04 to kernel 5.15.0-122
Newbie here.
I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my pc.
abhi@ubuntu:~$ uname -mrs
Linux 6.8.0-45-generic x86_64

abhi@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.5 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

I have a tool that works only on 5.15.0-122(or any 5.* kernel) and hence i want to update/downgrade the kernel.
Tried to follow the below link
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/11/install-ga-kernel-5-15-ubuntu-22-04/
On the reboot part, after selecting generic option, i ran into boot errors related to uuid. Unfortunately, no logs for this is available.
Can you please guide me how i can achieve this ?

This question is similar to: How to go back from HWE (5.13) to GA (5.4) kernel in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Official documentation is https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack where you just look for "To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel:".   Note that it suggests you test the kernel check BEFORE removing the unwanted packages... ie. if you don't remove the other stack you can have more than one kernel stack installed.   Also note some closed-source kernel modules (NVIDIA etc) can prevent multiple stacks co-existing on the same install, but if you're only using open-source kernel modules (aka drivers) multiple kernel stacks can be used.

Changing kernel stack will NOT cause a UUID problem; that usually is the result of a bad edit of the file-system table (/etc/fstab) or other unrelated to GA/HWE/OEM kernel stack changes..   For help on that issue, you should be specific as to what you did (not just instructions; as changing kernel stack will not cause a boot failure like you mention)
